# Error while sending QUERY packet in wp-db.php on line 1877

Tags: php, wordpress, line, pid

I know this question has been asked several times. But I haven't got the right answer yet.
As per suggestion this error may occur because of

```
– host’s memory limit
– mysql’s max_allowed_packet
– mysql’s wait_timeout
```

But I set "Allow cPanel & WHM to determine the best value for your MySQL max_allowed_packet configuration?" on in WHM. So now the server automatically determine the max_allowed_packet size. 
Currently it is 26 MB and following are the timeout values of the server.

```
connect_timeout     10
delayed_insert_timeout  300
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout     1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
interactive_timeout     28800
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
net_read_timeout    30
net_write_timeout   60
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
slave_net_timeout   3600
wait_timeout    300
```

Also there is no size issue on server. Please help me.